# I need to strip a field from url using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following string that I need to catch a `tag` from it.  Here is an example:

```
url = 'https://flank.xyz/contact/thank-you/?loginId=xsf234-22f8-48d3-c3d3-08d7c7f8b488&tag=17&institution=Company';
```

I need to catch the value of the `tag`;

Can you please help me find a way of doing it.

Comment: Is it 17 in this example?

Comment: check out my answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "split" function to parse string and then try to get proper value from it:

Try this one:

```
var url = "https://flank.xyz/contact/thank-you/?loginId=xsf234-22f8-48d3-c3d3-08d7c7f8b488&tag=17&institution=Company";    
var urlAux = url.split('&');
var urlTag = urlAux[1];
var urlValue = urlTag.split('=');
var tagUrlValue = urlValue[1];
console.log(tagUrlValue);
```

Comment: it is not safe, if tag move 2-3-4 place in params

Comment: @xdeepakv this is just an example if tag is always in same place, it can be searched in array to find "tag" and its value if param place is different

Comment: it would not be, anyway. was just suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

**Can use a util function**

```js
 const getQueryParams = url => {
      return url
        .split(/\/?\?/)[1]
        .split(/&/g)
        .reduce((m, v) => {
          const [key, val] = v.split("=");
          m[key] = val;
          return m;
        }, {});
    };
    const params = getQueryParams(
      "https://flank.xyz/contact/thank-you/?loginId=xsf234-22f8-48d3-c3d3-08d7c7f8b488&tag=17&institution=Company"
    );
    console.log(params.tag);
    console.log(params.institution);
    console.log(params.loginId);
```

```css
.as-console-row {color: blue!important}
```